# Can any one help me to rewrite the below query in db2

Tags: db2, query-optimization

Here is the **query**

```
select *
FROM 
WEBSS.P0022_INVENTORY_ACTIVITY_LOG I LEFT OUTER JOIN WEBSS.P0029_LOCATION L2 ON I.INVT_XFER_LOC_ID = L2.LOC_ID,
WEBSS.P0029_LOCATION L
WHERE 
I.LOC_ID = L.LOC_ID 
UNION ALL 
select *
FROM 
WEBSS.P0022_INVENTORY_ACTIVITY_LOG I LEFT OUTER JOIN WEBSS.P0029_LOCATION L2 ON I.LOC_ID = L2.LOC_ID,
WEBSS.P0029_LOCATION L
WHERE 
I.INVT_XFER_LOC_ID = L.LOC_ID;
```

Can you plz tell me hw can i use the **second query** in effective manner.

When you look at the query u can find there is a small change in the condition.. so for that do we really need to go for two queries nwith union all..

I need to tune the second query ie..any possible way to rewrite the second query to make good performance.. any help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to accomplish here?  Personally, I'd rather re-write the queries you've given to remove the `UNION`, and just tweak the conditions.  Oh, and the two are not equivalent - the `UNION` version is doing `(A AND B) OR (C AND D)`, whereas the other is doing `(A OR B) AND (C OR D)` (roughly).

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in db2, but sql statements are generally the same

- UNION ALL returns also duplicates
- use only Union in order not to return duplicates
- if you do not add "()" in the union it will be completed it will do the unions in the order you write them http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx
- why do you select from WEBSS.P0029_LOCATION L and not use also a left join? I would use two left joins and is it